# BigQuery: Exceeded quota for Number of partition modifications to a column partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I get this error when trying to run a lot of import CSV jobs on BigQuery date-partitioned with a custom `Timestamp` column.

> Your table exceeded quota for Number of partition modifications to a column partitioned table

Full error below:

`{Location: "partition_modifications_per_column_partitioned_table.long"; Message: "Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for Number of partition modifications to a column partitioned table. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors"; Reason: "quotaExceeded"}`

It is not clear to me on: What is the quota for `Number of partition modifications`? and how is it being exceeded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the quota for Number of partition modifications?

See [`Quotas for Partitioned tables`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#partitioned_tables)
In particular:

**Maximum number of partitions modified by a single job — 2,000**

> > Each job operation (query or load) can affect a maximum of 2,000 partitions. Any query or load job that affects more than 2,000 partitions is rejected by Google BigQuery.

**Maximum number of partition modifications per day per table — 5,000**

> > You are limited to a total of 5,000 partition modifications per day for a partitioned table. A partition can be modified by using an operation that appends to or overwrites data in the partition. Operations that modify partitions include: a load job, a query that writes results to a partition, or a DML statement (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE) that modifies data in a partition.

You can see more details in above link

Comment: In total, we have approximately 6500 CSVs to load with approx 110 days of data. And each csv has one day's data for one item. From what I understood that would result into one "partition modification" per csv - correct?

However, we see that only 389 CSV load jobs were successful before the error occurs. i.e. errs after 389 partition modifications

Comment: Why not load all of the files at once?

Comment: If your csv file contains data from 110 days, then one csv will result in 110 partition modification, as its data will be written to 110 partitions. As Elliott suggested, just load all the files at once. You'll only have 110 partition modifications in total.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Thanks - that makes sense. 

I'm not yet sure why I got stopped out at 389 instead of 5000 - but that should not be a problem after I combine the files.

Comment: Can you please provide the job_id of the job that saw this error after 389 partition modifications? Common reason is that there were other writes to that table that consumed this quota. (I don't need the project id, just the job_id and date on which it was run is sufficient).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna change the data often I strongly suggest you delete the table and simply upload it again with the new values. Every time you upload a new table, you get the limit refreshed.

Comment: I'm not sure that this works, I've deleted a table and hit exactly the same limit on my next run.